# Question about Standard Access Control List

Tags: network, router, network-access-control

According to my textbook, it states that a Standard ACL should be placed on the router interface as close to the destination as possible.

I am not sure what that means unless each router gets their own ACL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means like this: let's assume you have a configuration like:

`network1<-->router1<-->router2<-->router3<-->network2` .

if you want something to be denied for going into or getting out of network2, you put the ACL on router3 (which is closest to network2), not or router2 or 1 (which are further from your target compared to router3).

Standard ACL examine the source address only. As a result, you must place them as close to the destination as possible to avoid blocking traffic bound for another interface/network.